# when I load data from external file. I get error in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

When i load the data from external file,  I am getting error

```
   hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/decoders/Desktop/ml-100k/u.data' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE u_data;
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/URIException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzerFactory.get(SemanticAnalyzerFactory.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:977)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: How did you install Hive / hadoop?

Comment: i installed in linux using a tutorial.

Comment: Please provide link to tutorial, or start over trying the Hortonworks or Cloudera virtual machines that already set up everything for you